# How to avoid exponential slowdown in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I'm the owner of an online browser based game that has around 300 players signed up. I've written a script to detect cheaters, but the issue is that the number of queries in said script will grow exponentially.

It works like this:

1. Send a query that gets player's information.
2. Inside of the query, run another query that gets the information of every player.

So basically I am running a query that gets every player's name and information, and inside of that query I run another query to get the information from every other player besides themself. I use this to compare and delete cheaters.

The issue is, since I have 300 players, I have to run 300 queries per player. That's 90,000 queries. If I reach 1,000 players, it would be 1,000,000 queries. There has to be a better way to do this.

My code:

```
 <?php
    require '../connect.php';

    $rulerinfo = $conn->query("SELECT id, rulername, nationname, alliance, email, dateregister, user_agent, lastseen, password FROM players");
        while ($rulerinfo2 = $rulerinfo->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $rulerinfo2['id'];
            $rulername = $rulerinfo2['rulername'];
            $nationname = $rulerinfo2['nationname'];
            $alliance = $rulerinfo2['alliance'];
            $email = $rulerinfo2['email'];
            $dateregister = $rulerinfo2['dateregister'];
            $useragent = $rulerinfo2['user_agent'];
            $lastseen = $rulerinfo2['lastseen'];
            $password = $rulerinfo2['password'];

    $playerinfo = $conn->query("SELECT id, rulername, nationname, alliance, email, dateregister, user_agent, lastseen, password  FROM players WHERE id != '$id'");
        while ($playerinfo2 = $playerinfo->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id2 = $playerinfo2['id'];
            $rulername2 = $playerinfo2['rulername'];
            $nationname2 = $playerinfo2['nationname'];
            $alliance2 = $playerinfo2['alliance'];
            $email2 = $playerinfo2['email'];
            $dateregister2 = $playerinfo2['dateregister'];
            $useragent2 = $playerinfo2['user_agent'];
            $lastseen2 = $playerinfo2['lastseen'];
            $password2 = $playerinfo2['password'];

            $rulerdistance = levenshtein($rulername, $rulername2);
            $nationdistance = levenshtein($nationname, $nationname2);
            $emaildistance = levenshtein($email, $email2);
            $agentdistance = levenshtein($useragent, $useragent2) / 2;

            $totaldistance = $rulerdistance + $nationdistance + $emaildistance + $agentdistance;

            if ($password == $password2) {
                $totaldistance = $totaldistance - 20;
            }

            if ($totaldistance < 0) {
                $totaldistance = 0;
            }


        }

        }
?>
```

Comment: Show table structures and indexes, and the result of an EXPLAIN on the query

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you explain what an EXPLAIN is?

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ..... it gives lots of information about the tables, keys, and how the query joins (not mysql join) things together.  So basically just put "EXPLAIN" in front of your query.

Comment: Alright, I tried it, but nothing is appearing. @brechmos

Comment: It looks like you are getting all rows of `players` in memory, then stepping through the query again one by one. That's 1+300 queries, so not quite the 300^2 you mention (unless there is something I am not seeing). Why not load them all into memory, and then you can compare all with all much faster? That's one query. Moreover, you can do this offline on a cron, so you can increase the memory limits needed for larger numbers of users.

Comment: @user3798996: You would have to run it at the mysql prompt or maybe in PHPMyAdmin.  There is likely a way to do it in PHP as you are in the above code, but I would have to think about how to print the results. :)  [Ok, thought about it, you might be able to a `print_r($rulerinfo);`

Comment: (Aside on security: the passwords are not in plain text, and you've used `password_hash`, right?)

Comment: @halfer The passwords are salted, therefore I am just grabbing the salted passwords from the database.

Comment: Great, assuming you've used a decent hashing algorithm. See also my 19:17 comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should only do the query once, put it in an array and work with it from there. I don't see the need to make almost the same query twice. Loop in your array a second time and just check if the id is not the same as the current.

```
$res = $conn->query("SELECT id, rulername, nationname, alliance, email, dateregister, user_agent, lastseen, password FROM players");

$array=array();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

for($i=0; $i<count($array);$i++) {
   for($j=0; $j<count($array); $j++) {
      if ($i != $j) {
         // Call your functions
         $rulerdistance = levenshtein($array[$i]['rulername'], $array[$j]['rulername']);
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This should help a lot. I'll test it and see if I can get it working.

Comment: This worked like magic. I've spent hours looking up how to use arrays in queries like this, but had no luck. You are the best, @Johnny Drew

Comment: `$rulerinfo` and `$rulerinfo2` aren't ideal names. One is a result resource and the other is a row, so `$result` and `$row` might be better (and are commonly used). +1 anyway though.

Comment: @halfer indeed, I just kept the current code, but I will make the modifications.